# SymmetricDS sync to same node

Tags: symmetricds

I am trying track changes to a table via SymmetricDS (v3.7.32), use two specific columns and route them to another table on the same node.

I've added the trigger, router and trigger_router records, and my trigger seems to be working as I can see the record appearing in sym_data, however even with a table of exactly the same format, the table is not being loaded.

I cannot see relevant batches in sym_incoming_batch on the same server, which I assume I should from the same channel.

I have other tables being replicated, so the config is all correct, I am not seeing any errors on the batch, but nothing seems to be happening on the router side, though in sym_data_event, I can see that the record has the correct router_id ... it just doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Can anyone shed any light on this issue for me?

Answer (score 0):

I think that two engines will have to be declared declared on the same SymmetricDS instance to sync the data between two tables within the same DB

Comment: Hi @boris-pavlović, do you mean the entry in sym_node_group_link?  I have an entry in there will the same value in source_node_group_id and target_node_group_id.
I can't find anything about syncing inside the same database in the documentation that points that this would be an issue, but I'm a bit lost.

Comment: hm... have you thought about crafting a db trigger by hand that will be on insert/update/delete sync from one to other table? you don't need symmetricDS to solve this problem. existing symmetricDS triggers can be used as a starting point.

Comment: Yeah, I have, we just use Symmetric pretty comprehensively so people are familiar with it so that was my preference.  This is also hitting a couple of other systems so standard triggers have a couple of shortcomings that I was trying to avoid.